# Capturing Input and Providing Output with Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, output

I'm finally getting around to learning Javascript; I am trying to do something simple: capture keyboard input while providing output. I get semi-responsive output for keyboard presses, however I am not able to append the output portion of the page with a line of input once `enter` is pressed. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script language="javascript">
    processCommand = function(cmd) {
        if (this.text == null) this.text = "";
        this.text = this.text + cmd + "<br>";
        document.getElementById("outputID") = this.text;
    }
    document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
        if (this.text == null) this.text = ""; 
        var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode);
        this.text = this.text + keyChar;
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
            processCommand(this.text);
            this.text = "";
        }
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = this.text;
    };
</script>
<spad id="outputID"/><br>
<hr>
<spad id="input"/>
```

Comment: It's `document.getElementById("outputID").innerHTML = this.text` not `document.getElementById("outputID") = this.text;`.

Comment: First thing I would do is introduce a variable for `document.getElementById("outputID") ` and `document.getElementById("input") ` elements. No need to look them up on every key press

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gavNOm

```
<script language="javascript">
 processCommand = function(cmd) {
    if (this.text == null) this.text = "";
    this.text = this.text + cmd + "<br>";
    outputID.innerHTML = this.text;
}
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    if (this.text == null) this.text = ""; 
    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(evt.keyCode);
    this.text = this.text + keyChar;
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
        processCommand(this.text);
        this.text = "";
    }
    input.innerHTML = this.text;
   };
 </script>
 <span id="outputID"/><br>
<hr>
<span id="input"/>
```

The id's are attached to the window object, by the way using vars in functions is much less confusing.

Comment: `this.text` in both functions are intended to be two separate variables

Comment: ok thanks for the tips. now I need to discover why `processCommand` seems to work only once